# matching associations and no associated record cakephp 3

Tags: orm, associations, matching, cakephp-3.1

I have an association of `Price` belongsTo `Season`

I am trying to query all prices that match a specific date range when passed in the season as well as any that have none (`Prices.season_id=0`)

Here is what I have:

```
// build the query
$query = $this->Prices->find()
  ->where(['product_id'=>$q['product_id']])
  ->contain(['Seasons']);

if(!empty($to_date) && !empty($from_date)) {
  $query->matching('Seasons', function ($q) {
    return $q->where([
      'from_date <= ' => $to_date,
      'to_date >= ' => $from_date
    ]);
  });
}
```

However, this will only return Prices explicitly associated with a Season. How do I make it return Prices.season_id=0 also?

Answer (score 0):

The `$query->matching()` call internally creates a `INNER JOIN` and places the where-statements of the callback-function into the `ON` clause of the join. For retrieving items without the association you need a `LEFT JOIN`. So your codesnippet would look like this:

```
if(!empty($to_date) && !empty($from_date)) {
    $query->leftJoinWith('Seasons', function ($q){return $q;});
    $query->where([[
        'or' => [
            'Season.id IS NULL',
            [
                'from_date <= ' => $to_date,
                'to_date >= ' => $from_date,
            ],
        ],
    ]]);
}
```

So we create a normal `INNER JOIN` and place the conditions in the normal (outmost) `where` clause of the query.

The double array is for disambiguation of probably other where conditions with an `or` connection.

I myself stumbled over the `column IS NULL` instead of `'column' => null` syntax.

PS: This works for all associations. For `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` you have to group the results with `$query->group('Prices.id')`